# valid characters in SVN paths

Tags: svn

What are the valid characters in an SVN path? I can't seem to find any documentation that specifies this.

For example, the [SVN 1.7 Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.checkout.html) says the SVN command for checkout is

```
svn checkout URL[@REV]... [PATH]
```

but never defines what constitutes a valid `URL` or `PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

- Valid URL - [RFC 3986, part 2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2)
- PATH - any (OS-specific) valid string

Comment: Yeah, that's the obvious answer, but it's not the right answer. The reason I know it's not the right answer is that SVN defines `@` as the delimiter for a revision, so for example `http://example.com/svn/repo/pa@th/to@/file_that_I@like` would not be a valid path. SVN doesn't seem to have a spec stating what characters are valid/invalid in the URL.

Comment: According to https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2.2 `@` is a gen-delim, i.e. general delimiter, so can't be part of a URI - only used a delimiter (it would need to be %escaped). So the address you've suggested is not a valid path.